# Power adaptor for a 1080 Ti graphics card

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, adapter

I have a 1080 Ti that requires two power connections: a 6-pin and a 8-pin.

The power supply (the 700W in an HP-Z440 workstation) has more than enough raw power, but the connectors are an issue.

It has these available power connectors:
- 2x 6-pin
- 2x SATA
- 1 4-pin (molex)

Theoretically, the 6-pin plus either the 4-pin molex or one of the SATAs should be wireable to the 8-pin, to give the required 150W.

Does anyone know of an available adapter to do this?

The 2x SATAs could be adapted to the 8-pin (there are standard adapters for this), but I'm unsure if the SATAs will actually carry enough power.

I could just use a 6-to-8 pin adapter (the guy at HP had just configured a system like that). It would probably run with the limited power draw, but would likely hamper it's performance, which is going to be undesirable for my needs.

*Edit*: 2 other possible configurations, that use 2 adapters instead of 1.
1. 2x SATA -> adapter -> 6 pin on GPU, and 2x 6 pin -> adapter -> 8 pin on GPU.
2. 2x SATA -> adapter -> 6 pin, plus the original 6 pin -> adapter -> 8 pin. (GPU 6 pin plugged directly)

Answer (score 1):

I have been in almost the same situation: 2 Titans in SLI in a Z440.

We used both 6-pin plugs directly on the Titans and used Molex to 8-Pin adapters for those 8-pin connectors. (My colleague sourced these adapters, but I don't know from where and I can't ask him as a left the company some months ago. If you are in the US I know that Newegg and Amazon both carry them.)
The wires to the Molex plugs can carry enough power without issues. We actually tested to see it they got warm after prolonged use (running 24 hours on the Unigine Heaven benchmark with maximum display settings) and everything stayed stable without overheating the wires.

With just 1 Geforce you should be absolutely fine.

Comment: Thank you for the info. It sounds like the simplest solution - a single 6 to 8 pin adapter - will probably work.

Comment: @Underhill in your case that would make most sense, I agree.